# how do I determine which columns in a JTable are visible

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I'm resizing my columns according to their data with the following:

```
  /**
   * Set the widths of the columns in the table according to the data in the table.
   * @param table
   */
  private static void setColumnWidths(JTable table)
  {
    int columnCount = table.getModel().getColumnCount();
    int rowCount = table.getModel().getRowCount();

    TableColumnModel columnModel = table.getColumnModel();

    for (int col=0; col<columnCount; col++)
    {
      TableColumn column = columnModel.getColumn(col);
      TableCellRenderer renderer = column.getCellRenderer();
      if (renderer == null)
      {
        renderer = new DefaultTableCellRenderer();
      }
      int overallColumnWidth = 0;
      for (int row = 0; row < rowCount; row++)
      {
        Object value = table.getValueAt(row, col);
        Component component = renderer.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, false, false, row, col);
        int componentWidth = (int) component.getPreferredSize().getWidth();
        overallColumnWidth = Math.max(componentWidth, overallColumnWidth);
      }
      column.setPreferredWidth(overallColumnWidth);
    }
  }
```

This works when all the columns are visible, but I've got code that hides some of them (`JTable.removeColumn(TableColumn column)`).  It appears that both the JTable instance and the TableColumnModel instance have the list of data columns, i.e., all columns regardless of visibility.  How can I get a list of only columns that are visible, or test whether a given column is visible?

(I've searched for this, but get longs lists of articles on how to hide the columns, and no explanation of where the visible/invisible information is kept.  I thought, since I asked the JTable to hide the column, that somewhere in there it would know which columns were hidden and I could get that info.)

Comment: How are you hiding the columns?

Comment: `JTable.removeColumn(TableColumn column)` -- didn't know there was another way, without rebuilding the entire table

Comment: `TableColumn` has a `modelIndex` property which determines which column in the model they are representing.  You need to use the `TableColumnModel` to determine which columns are still remaining in the model, and not use the `TableModel` `columnCount` property, you then need to marry the `TableColumn` from the `TableColumnModel` to the data in the `TableModel`...

Comment: @MadProgrammer are you suggesting to use `table.getColumnModel().getColumnCount()` instead of `table.getModel().getColumnCount()`?

Comment: @KDM Yes, the `TableModel` is used by the `JTable` to create the `TableColumnModel` initially (by default), this is no (real) connection after between the two after that, so when you remove a column from the `TableColumnModel`, it still exists (at least the name) in the `TableModel`

Comment: `It appears that both the JTable instance and the TableColumnModel instance have the list of data columns, i.e., all columns regardless of visibility.` - Why do you say that? In you last question you stated: *The problem I have is that, once I remove the column, it is no longer in the TableColumnModel* and you where given an answer that confirmed that statement.

Comment: @KDM, you can just use `table.getColumnCount()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with your code if that your loops is controlled by the values returned in the TableMdoel.

Instead you should be using values from the table:

```
int rowCount = table.getRowCount();
int columnCount = table.getRowCount();
```

Then there is no need for exception logic to determine if a column is visible or not because by default it will be visible because it is the job of the view (JTable) to only display visible columns.

You need to understand the difference between the "view" and the "model".

> how do I determine which columns in a JTable are visible

So the better answer is to use the methods of the JTable. Your current solution confuses the view and model.

You could also use the [Table Column Adjuster](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/10/table-column-adjuster/) to do the column adjustment for you. It provides features like dynamically resizing the column as the data changes.

Comment: You're right, I am confused about model and view in JTable.  By getting columns from JTable instead of the (data)model, I now adjust only those columns that are in view.  And I'm still not clear on column model -- it appears that calling JTable.getColumnModel() does return a column model of those columns that are in view only.  So I guess that model is also view.  Am not sure where the model is for the columns, perhaps there isn't one.  I've changed the accepted answer to this one, it is much superior to the other.

Answer (score 6):

Check if `table.convertColumnIndexToView(col)` returns -1.

From the documentation:

> public int convertColumnIndexToView(int modelColumnIndex)
>
> Maps the index of the column in the table model at modelColumnIndex to
>   the index of the column in the view. Returns the index of the
>   corresponding column in the view; **returns -1 if this column is not
>   being displayed**. If modelColumnIndex is less than zero, returns
>   modelColumnIndex.

[Source](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#convertColumnIndexToView(int))

Comment: Thanks -- for those later readers who might not know, like I didn't, the method is on JTable.

Comment: I don't recommend this solution. The answer is based on the OP's confusion on how the model/view work. If the code only worries about the view (as it should) then there is no need for this additional check.

Comment: I felt I had to change the accepted answer from this one to camickr's -- it is certainly much superior.